# Expand Expandable Listview in android on button Click

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am implementing expandable list view with its custom adapter. The group element needs to have 2 buttons, first as a parent group element and a button below it.

My problem is, I want to expand the list view on click of the button below instead of the group element. Also, the group element `onClick` needs to call another activity.

I can disable the expanding of the `expandablelistview`  by

```
mainExpListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) 
    {   

        return false;
    }
```

So my questions:

1. Is there any way to disable the group element and get it to perform other functions (Like navigate to another activity?)
2. How to set an `onclick` method on them bottom image to expand?

[image]

Comment: Your question is bit unclear to me. If you want to expand the group on press of button then you can do something like this `list_expandable.expandGroup(position);`. Where `position` is the index of that group in list and indexing starts from zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
 this is the groupview of my adapter and expand is the button on which i am performing  expand and collapse of my expanded list.



    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.childlist_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        ImageView expand = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand);
        if (isExpanded) {
            expand.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_selected);
        } else {
            expand.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp);
        }
        expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // frag.expandandcollapse(isExpanded,groupPosition);
                if (isExpanded) ((ExpandableListView) parent).collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                else ((ExpandableListView) parent).expandGroup(groupPosition, true);
            }
        });
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);


        return convertView;
    }


therefore one more thing to keep in mind u have to override the default expand and collapse of your expandedlistview.........just change the return type of on groupclick listner from false to true


example
ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener()
 {
            @Override

            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) 
{


                String groupNvalue = MyApp.getInstance().categoryNvalues.get(groupPosition);
                Showtoast(groupNvalue);

                return true;///this has to be changed to true in your activity or fragment
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure  but 
in the adapter you can set on click listener on your view

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int pos, boolean arg1, View convertView, ViewGroup arg3) {

if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) act
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawerlayout, null);
    }
      convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })
   }
```